# How do I do cross-project refactorings with ropemacs?

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, ropemacs, rope

I have a file structure that looks something like this:

```
project1_root/
    tests/
        ...
    src/
        .ropeproject/
        project1/
            ... (project1 source code)

project2_root/
    tests/
        ...
    src/
        .ropeproject/
        project2/
            ... (project2 source)
```

I'm frequently switching back and forth between these two projects, and project2 depends on project1.  What is the best way to set up ropemacs to handle this?  It would be nice if I could facilitate cross-project refactorings (which I see mentioned in the rope library reference), but I'll be happy if I can at least keep both projects open at once without having to switch back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documention on ropemacs and ropemode seems to be very sparse (the homepage http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropemacs.html only point to the mercurial repos, which I checked out and read through the code), but it seems you can give a specific .ropeproject to use, and it may be guess it (ropemode/interfaces.py:_guess_project) by searching up in the directory tree for a .ropeproject directory.

So it should be fairly easy to hack around the issue by creating a (new) .ropeproject which covers both projects if you create a specific .ropeproject for project1/ and project2/ .

Disadvantages that I see might be that you might have to move the orignal .ropeproject dirs out of the way, and it needs some extra scripting to manage ropeproject directories over more than 2 projects.